# Rails extremely slow database querying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

My app currently has a table that has around 12.8 million rows in it and that table has a `has_one` association with another 5 tables where each of them has the same 12.8 million rows in them.

All of these data will then be displayed in a table with filtering capabilities using the `filterrific` gem. The problem is that it takes too much time to do queries like column specific searching whereas a `Table.count` query takes around 30-40 seconds to complete. Are there any query optimization methods that could greatly decrease the query time?

I have tried implementing eager load and selecting required columns to display only but the performance increase has not been significant.

Example schema:

**domain.rb**

```
create_table "domains", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                                     null: false
    t.integer  "age",                      default: 0
    t.integer  "pr",                       default: 0
    t.boolean  "dmoz",                     default: false
    t.float    "price",                    default: 0.0
    t.string   "listing_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",                               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               null: false
    t.string   "source"
    t.datetime "end_date_time"
    t.integer  "no_bids",                  default: 0
    t.float    "traffic",                  default: 0.0
    t.float    "valuation",                default: 0.0
  end
add_index "domains", ["name"], name: "index_domains_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
```

For the search filters, scopes are used and an example below:

```
  scope :basic, lambda { |basic|
    query = ""
    query += "age BETWEEN #{check_min(basic.age_min.to_i)} AND #{check_max(basic.age_max.to_i)} " if basic.age_min.present? || basic.age_max.present?
    query += "AND price BETWEEN #{check_min(basic.price_min.to_f)} AND #{check_max(basic.price_max.to_f)} " if basic.price_min.present? || basic.price_max.present?
    query += "AND pr BETWEEN #{check_min(basic.pr_min.to_i)} AND #{check_max(basic.pr_max.to_i)} " if basic.pr_min.present? || basic.pr_max.present?
    if query[0..2] == 'AND'
      query = query[3..-1]
    end

    where(query)
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on your schema and how you are searching on it? It sounds like you need more/better indexes but without more details it is hard to say what would speed things up.

Comment: Is it count or querying that you want to optimize?  Given the size of the table, is an approximate value sufficient for count?

Comment: Hey guys, I have just added some additional details. I would like to speed up both the count and querying if possible. @ChrisTravers an approximate value would be sufficient if it reduces the time significantly. How can I get the approximate value by the way?

Answer (score 0):

To get an approximate row count, do as follows in SQL

```
SELECT reltuples AS approximate_row_count 
  FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'domains';
```

Now you have not provided the generated SQL or query plans so here is some general advice to get you going.  I may add a little more specific advice as more info comes in but that is somewhat limited.

SQL is a declarative language, meaning we tell the db what we want and try to make sure it can do it fast.  So what you want to do is to log slow statements (`log_min_duration_statement` in your postgresql.conf) and then explain analyze those statements.  Without a query plan it is very hard to see what indexes might be needed.

The query plan basically tells you what PostgreSQL decided, given the indexes available, was the fastest way to retrieve the data you wanted.  From there you want to look at selective criteria (i.e the ways to cut out the most rows) and index those fields if you are getting sequential scans over large tables unexpectedly (sequential scans are usually faster, however, when you are retrieving around 10% of the table).